# Redirect urls using htaccess - using mysql too

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to change the URLs in my website from

```
http://www.example.com/games.php?game=600
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/games/gamename
```

the "gamename" is a field in the MySQL database.

i draw it like this to the page title `<?=$data['enname']?>`

I guess I need to do it in the `.htaccess` file with `RewriteRule`

but I don't know how exactly

can someone help?

Comment: A rewrite rule in .htaccess could pass the name in your pretty URL to a script by calling `/games.php?name=gamename` but I can't handle database lookups.  Can you say more about what you have tried and what specific errors you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting isn't possible with `.htaccess` alone - where is the `600` expected to come from? To do this in `.htaccess` alone, the `600` would need to be present in the requested URL. eg. `/games/600/gamename`

Then you could do something like the following in `.htaccess` to map `/games/600/gamename` to `/games.php?game=600`:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/games/(\d+)/ games.php?game=$1 [L]
```

NB: MultiViews needs to be disabled here since you are using a URL-path segment that maps directly to the basename of an existing file. ie. `/games` and `/games.php`. If MultiViews was enabled then `/games.php` would be called (by mod_negotiation) without any URL parameters.

Otherwise, if you want to use the URL `/games/gamename` (without the "id") then you would need a front-controller. eg. Rewrite all requests to `games.php` (as before) but then lookup `gamename` in your DB (to retrieve the "id") using PHP and serve the appropriate content.

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/games/([\w-]+)$ games.php?gamename=$1 [L]
```

Note the change in URL parameter. The "gamename" is passed to your script instead of the "id". You then lookup the game "id" in yours `games.php` script to serve the appropriate content.

**UPDATE:** Obviously this does require that "gamename" is a unique (and indexed) field in your DB. If not then you have no option but to include the "id" (eg. `600`) in the requested URL, as mentioned in the first half of my answer.

Comment: the 600 is the game id in the sql database

Comment: @yogev Ok, but you also stated: "the "gamename" is a field in the MySQL database". If "gamename" is not unique then the "id" (ie. `600`) _must_ be present in the initial URL - as stated in the first part of my answer. (I've updated my answer to clarify this.)

Comment: @yogev You're welcome. If my answer helped then please mark it as "accepted" (checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to help other readers, remove it from the unanswered question queue and to show your appreciation :). When you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)